# zfs "Permanent errors" in "rpool/USERDATA"

Tags: zfs

`zpool statuts -v` gives me `Permanent errors`, and I was wondering how to fix them:

```
❯  sudo zpool status -v
Insert authentication card for user `franck'
[sudo] Mot de passe de franck : 
  pool: bpool
 state: ONLINE
config:

        NAME                                    STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        bpool                                   ONLINE       0     0     0
          0f41ddf7-006b-9641-852a-c77eebf4ad89  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

  pool: rpool
 state: ONLINE
status: One or more devices has experienced an error resulting in data
        corruption.  Applications may be affected.
action: Restore the file in question if possible.  Otherwise restore the
        entire pool from backup.
   see: https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/msg/ZFS-8000-8A
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 00:07:34 with 6 errors on Tue May  9 16:57:56 2023
config:

        NAME                                                 STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        rpool                                                ONLINE       0     0     0
          10c839c4-470f-094f-a176-ee56727ec520               ONLINE       8     0     0
          nvme-Samsung_SSD_970_EVO_Plus_2TB_S4J4NX0R857127E  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: Permanent errors have been detected in the following files:

        rpool/USERDATA/franck_4tpcmt:<0x2f1d1c>
        rpool/USERDATA/franck_4tpcmt:<0x3d0d74>
        rpool/USERDATA/franck_4tpcmt:<0x273da2>
        rpool/USERDATA/franck_4tpcmt:<0xcd6ba>
        rpool/USERDATA/franck_4tpcmt:<0x2aadc6>
        rpool/USERDATA/franck_4tpcmt:<0x3d0df0>
```

I am not sure what `rpool/USERDATA/franck_4tpcmt` stands for, and I'm even more confused by the `:<xxxxx>` after that.

What does it mean, and how to fix the "permanent errors" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at a [similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/576898/clear-a-permanent-zfs-error-in-a-healthy-pool), it seems this is a problem with corrupted/orphaned inodes (`<0x2f1d1c>` is an inode ID), likely because the file has been deleted, but the inode is still referenced by ZFS.

The solution seems to be forcing a scrub:

```
sudo zpool scrub rpool
```

If a complete scrub doesn't clear the errors, it is suggested to start the scrub, let it run for some time, and force it to stop again with:

```
sudo zpool scrub -s rpool
```

In addition, this can occur if a running application is still referencing the inodes of deleted files. In this case, simply **rebooting** the machine will allow the inodes to be freed, and the ZFS errors will likely disappear. More information about this can be found [here](http://unixetc.co.uk/2012/01/22/zfs-corruption-persists-in-unlinked-files/).

Comment: Initially my pool was in DEGRADED state, with too many errors. I ran scrub, and after that, these inode errors remain. Running scrub again is instantaneous, but does not correct the errors.

Comment: Reading the similar question, I realized that deleted files still hold by a process could be the culprits. I just rebooted and the error is gone...